# How to use maths operation with Joi.ref() for validating object using Joi?

Tags: javascript, json, validation, object, joi

I want to validate object using Joi which inovle use of Joi.ref() with multiplication operation.

```
var object = {
    a: 5,
    b: 6
}

// this is wrong as Joi.ref('a')*2 is now allowed in max()
var schema = Joi.object({
    a: Joi.number().integer(),
    b: Joi.number().integer().min(1).max(Joi.ref('a')*2)
})
```

`Joi.ref('a')*2` is not allowed. So how can I validate object such that `b<=2*a`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`adjust`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#refkey-options) option

```
var schema = Joi.object({
    a: Joi.number().integer(),
    b: Joi.number().integer().min(1).max(Joi.ref('a', {
      adjust: (value) => value * 2
    }))
})
```

[**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-kpagbu?file=index.js)